# i set fabric env.skip_bad_hosts=True,but it has no effect

Tags: fabric

There are some bad hosts in my host_list,so i set env.skip_bad_hosts=True,
but it ahs no effect, fabric already abort because of Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to myip

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding try:...except:...,exceptional handling。